# I am obliged to restart my computer savagely , when I lock the screen for a long time

Tags: lightdm

I have a problem with my Sony Vaio SVS1311F3E/W .

When  I log in, after have locked the screen for a long period of time, the screen will be black and I can see only the mouse, so I am obliged to restart my computer, savagely.

Processor    : Intel Core i5-3210M.

Graphic card : Intel HD Graphics 4000.

RAM          : 4 Go.

OS           : Ubuntu 12.04 .

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you running?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the same problem. I find if I wait long enough the system will respond, but how long it takes depends upon how long it has been locked.

I suggest that you either:

1. turn off the screen power off option in the `Brightness and Lock` settings program.
2. Use Unity 2D rather than full Unity so you aren't using Compiz. This is selected from the pull down from where you login to your account.

I believe this is compiz bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/969860 even though I'm not using fglrx myself. I find I can get around it by using a terminal elsewhere, confirming that compiz is using a lot of CPU, and killing compiz.